# Python script to alert on empty/missing logs

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, system-administration

I am working on a project to check a file directory and automatically add log files as they are created. A file is being generated every five minutes, but some of the files are being created with a "0" filesize and I would like to alert when this happens.

So the sequence of steps I would like to have are essentially:

- Get time (MM:DD:YY HH:MM:SS) *Not sure if I need to do this...
- CD to Folder Directory /Netflow/YY/MM/DD
- Search for filename "nfcapd.YYYYMMDDHHMM" where MM increments by 5.
- If filesize is 0, then email Johnny, Sally and Jimmy
- Wait 6 minutes and repeat

This is what I have pieced together thus far. How can I get the desired functionality?

```
import os
def is_non_zero_file(fpath): storage/Netflow/  
return True if os.path.isfile(fpath) and os.path.getsize(fpath) > 0 else False

# I need to check storage/Netflow for files named by time e.g 13_56_05.txt

while True:
time.sleep(360)
```

Comment: `os.listdir()` is your friend, as is the `stat` module

Comment: I think I am having more difficulty figuring out how to search for the file name based on time.

Comment: `os.listdir()` gives you a list of all the filenames, `x in y` tells you if the string x is in the string y. Get the list of names and a string representation of time. Read the documentation for the `time` module for that last one. That should be enough.

Comment: cool, thanks! As I said, I am just getting into this so I will have to do some reading. I appreciate the pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to enumerating the files in a given path, and subsequently filtering the files which are only zero-length, you probably want to maintain some type of state to ensure you're aren't notified multiple times of the same zero length file. That is, you probably don't want to get a notification that the same file is zero-length indefinitely (although you can modify the example below if you want said behavior).

You may optionally want to do things like verify that the file name strictly meets your naming convention. You may also want to validate the the string date-stamp included in the file name is a valid datetime.

The example below uses the glob module (itself leveraging `os.listdir()` and `fnmatch.fnmatch()`) to build up a set of possible files for inclusion. [1]

The example is intentionally simple, and leverages a single class to store log sample 'state'. `KEEP_SAMPLES` samples are maintained (instances of `logState()` in the `log_states` list, achieved by using list slicing.

A single `alert(msg)` function is supplied as a stub to something that might send mail, etc...

References:

[1] https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/glob.html

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import glob
import re
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import time
from pprint import pprint

class logState():

    def __init__(self, log_path, glob_patt, re_patt, dt_fmt):

        self.dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
        self.log_path = log_path
        self.glob_patt = glob_patt
        self.re_patt = re_patt
        self.dt_fmt = dt_fmt
        self.empty_logs = []
        self.nonempty_logs = []

        # Retrieve only files from glob
        self.files = [  f for f in
                glob.glob(self.log_path + self.glob_patt)
                if os.path.isfile(f) ]

        for f in self.files:

            unq_fname = f.split('/')[-1]

            if unq_fname == None:
                continue

            # Tighter pattern matching
            if re.match(re_patt, unq_fname) == None:
                continue

            # Get the datetime portion of the file name
            f_dtstamp = unq_fname.split('.')[-1]

            # Make sure the datetime stamp represents
            # a valid date
            if datetime.strptime(f_dtstamp, self.dt_fmt) == None:
                continue

            # Check file size, add to the appropriate
            # list
            if os.path.getsize(f) <= 0:
                self.empty_logs.append(f)
            else:
                self.nonempty_logs.append(f)

def alert(msg):
    print("ALERT!: {0}".format(msg))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # How long to sleep
    SLEEP_SECS = 5

    # How many samples to keep
    KEEP_SAMPLES = 5

    log_states = []

    # Definition for what logs states we'll look for
    log_path = './'
    glob_patt = 'nfcapd.[0-9]*'
    re_patt = 'nfcapd.([0-9]{12})'
    dt_fmt = "%Y%m%d%H%M"

    print("-- Setup --")
    print("Sample files in '{0}'".format(log_path))
    print("\t{0} samples kept:".format(KEEP_SAMPLES))
    print("\tglob pattern: '{0}'".format(glob_patt))
    print("\tregex pattern: '{0}'".format(re_patt))
    print("\tdatetime string: '{0}'".format(dt_fmt))
    print("")

    # Collect the initial state
    log_states.append(logState(log_path, 
                               glob_patt, 
                               re_patt, dt_fmt))

    while True:

        # Print state inventory and current state detail
        print( "-- Log States Stored --")
        for i, log_state in enumerate(log_states):
            print("Log state {0} @ {1}".format(i, log_state.dt))

        print(" -- Logs size > 0 --")
        pprint(log_states[-1].nonempty_logs)
        print(" -- Logs size <= 0 --")
        pprint(log_states[-1].empty_logs)
        print("")

        time.sleep(SLEEP_SECS)
        log_states = log_states[-KEEP_SAMPLES+1:]

        log_states.append(logState(log_path, 
                                   glob_patt, 
                                   re_patt, 
                                   dt_fmt))

        # p = previous sample, c = current
        p = set(log_states[-2].empty_logs)
        c = set(log_states[-1].empty_logs)

        # only report the items in the current sample
        # not in the last
        if len(c.difference(p)) > 0:
            alert("\nNew zero length logs: " + str(c.difference(p)) + "\n")
```

Comment: wow... it's going to take me a while to work my way through that. I really appreciate that. I'd upvote if I could.. thanks so much!